# Blocks with no return value

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-blocks

Is there a proper way to write a block with no return value in Objective-C? All the examples that I have seen are all with return values. Can someone also please explain the difference between a completion block & a regular block? I know the ^ means that it is a block but doesn't the + before (void) mean it is a block as well?

Comment: http://goshdarnblocksyntax.com/

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13193673/how-do-i-create-an-objective-c-method-that-return-a-block

Comment: Go through this, I hope you will get to know
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html

Comment: + before a function makes it a class method instead of an instance method, aka static vs non-static functions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a demo:
1、no return values and no parameter:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];

//block
void(^myBlock)(void)  = ^(void) {
    NSLog(@"This is a block without parameter and returned value");
};
myBlock();
```

2、no return values and have parameter:

```
-(void)blockWithParameterButNoReturnData
{
    void(^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
        NSLog(@"%d",num*100);
    };
    myBlock(4);
}
```

3、have retrun values and have parameter:
-(void)blockWithParameterAndReturnValue

```
{
    int (^myBlock)(int) = ^(int num) {
        return num * 100;
    };
   int result =  myBlock(2);
    NSLog(@"This is a block with parameter and return value :%d",result);
}
```

PS:for more infomation,see this website:http://www.cnblogs.com/zhanggui/p/4656440.html

Comment: do you need to have a parameter to pass??

Comment: I don't understand what you say.

Answer (score 5):

Here is what a method header would look like if it has a parameter of a block:

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^)(parameterTypes))blockName;
```

So a block with no return type and no parameters would look something like this:

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(void (^)(void))blockName;
```

A regular block is just a set (or group) of code. A completion block is a block that will be executed when the method is completed. A completion block is a regular block, it just is specific to being called at the end of a method.

The `^` signifies a block. The `+` before a method is a class method.

### Other ways to use blocks

#### As a local variable

```
returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes) = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

#### As a property

```
@property (nonatomic, copy) returnType (^blockName)(parameterTypes);
```

#### As a method parameter

```
- (void)someMethodThatTakesABlock:(returnType (^)(parameterTypes))blockName;
```

#### As an argument to a method call

```
[someObject someMethodThatTakesABlock:^returnType (parameters) {...}];
```

#### As a typedef

```
typedef returnType (^TypeName)(parameterTypes);
TypeName blockName = ^returnType(parameters) {...};
```

You would just replace `returnType` with `void`.